# Reset daloradius password

Tags: freeradius, radius

I forget my Daloradius password. So, I want to reset my password. I am using **freeradius**, **mariadb** and **apache** for this lab. Please help me!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Al1.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question does not seem to be about programming. Your question could be more appropriate on one of the many stackexchange sites, may be serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok right now. It can check in mysql database. Login to db and can check in operators table in radius db you import from daloradius.